# Using CSS justify to distribute width of body with image and text under

Tags: css

Can't seem to get this working - i have a group of images with text under them set to :block , when i try to get the ul or li class containing the images and the a class , i'm unable to get anything i've tried to work. I want to keep images and text under the image centered regardless of page width.

Set up jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/89bnF/488/

HTML

```
<li class="single">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a><a>Top Dawg</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a><a>THEEOhiostate</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a><a>slambodians</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a><a>Hollywood Shuffler</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a><a>Thunderbolts</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a><a>MeWantee</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a><a>Cincy Slammers</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a><a>Mahafaha</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a><a>SF Drug Lords</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a><a>Hudy Delight</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a><a>long shot</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a><a>Green Guy</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

CSS

```
.single ul {
    text-align: justify;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.single li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 1.2em;
}

.single ul:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -1.2em;
}

.single ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
img {
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    background:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `position:relative` and introduce the `margin: 0 auto;` it should centre the `<li>`

```
.single li {
   display: inline-block;
   top: 1.2em;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```